# Duplicate detection window on Azure Service Bus Queue

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have an Azure Service Bus Queue with duplicate detection enabled.  The default time window for the duplicate history is 10 minutes, which I would like to change.  However whenever I do this within the Azure portal it seemingly accepts the change but then immediately reverts back to 10 minutes whenever I go back to the properties page.  Does anyone know a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Service Bus Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer). The portal might have an issue.

Comment: Looks like a bug with the portal then :)

Comment: There's also an issue with the queue size drop down list that doesn't seem to retain the value.